# Read GML for JP2 using OpenJPEG library?

Tags: jpeg2000

The title sums it all up. But i must explain, that i don't seek GDAL solution. My aim is to read entire JP2 file with georeference using only OpenJPEG and my geoprojections library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, it's not really an answer, its a piece of general advice:

Don't waste your time - Use GDAL for that one.